# Quick sort last step incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, quicksort

I am writing a code for Quick Sort of a list in Python 3.6.

At every step I have printed out the values of i and j (the two variables that I have used) along with the list (also, the values that are being swapped). The code works fine until the last step i.e. the swapping of 40 and 50. After placing the 60, it doesn't move further to this last step (swapping 40, 50). I'm not sure why this happens. Until then, everything is good.

** I have tried to write the program on my own, so please ignore the efficiency of the algorithm for the time being (although, any suggestions are welcome)

```
L=[35, 10, 40, 20, 60, 30, 90, 70, 50]

l=0
h=9

def partition (L, l, h):
    print("\n########## Partition() invoked: ",l,h)
    pivot = L[l]
    i = l
    j = h
    #print(i,j)
    while i<j:
        print(pivot, "***********", L)
        while True:
            i=i+1
            print("i=",i, L[i])
            if L[i]>pivot or i>=len(L):

                break
        while True:
            j=j-1
            print("j=",j, L[j])
            if L[j]<=pivot or j<0:
                break
        print("Check greater", i, j)
        if i>j:
            break
        print("Swapping: ",L[i],L[j])
        L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]

    print("l=", L[l], "  j=", L[j], L)
    j_val=L[j]
    l_val=L[l]
    L[l]=j_val
    L[j]=l_val
    print("l=", L[l], " j=", L[j] , l, j,  L)
    return i


def QuickSort( L, l, h):
    print(l, h)
    j = partition(L, l, h)
    partition(L, l, j+1)
    partition(L, j, h)

QuickSort(L,l,h)
print(L)
```

My final result : `[10, 20, 30, 35,`**50, 40**`, 60, 70, 90]` (after putting 60 in the right place, the program ended)

I have tried the following change to the QuickSort function (after referring to other answers), but the results are even more messed up...

```
def QuickSort( L, l, h):
    print(l, h)
    j = partition(L, l, h)
    partition(L, l, j)
    partition(L, j+1, h)
```

Comment: I've not fully investigated your code, but your definition of `QuickSort` is wrong. Your last two function calls should be recursive calls to `QuickSort`, otherwise you'll only partition three times and then quit. You do need to add a base case somewhere to stop the recursion.

Comment: Okay... I get that. Is it possible to make changes to the same code, to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `QuickSort` is incorrect. It's not recursive, it just calls `partition` three times, which won't fully sort lists with more than a few elements. The later two calls should be recursive calls to `QuickSort` instead.

Of course, when you make the code recursive, you also need to add a base case so the recursion will end. Fortunately, it's easy to see when further sorting is not needed by looking at `l` and `h`. A portion of the list with fewer than two elements in it doesn't need any more sorting.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def QuickSort(L, l, h):
    if h - l < 2:            # add a base case
        return
    j = partition(L, l, h)
    QuickSort(L, l, j)       # recurse
    QuickSort(L, j+1, h)     # here too
```

As a side note, using `l` (lowercase L) as a variable name is generally discouraged, as in some fonts it is very hard to tell the difference between it and a `1` (a one digit). I'd also avoid using variables that differ only in case (as `l` and `L` do). Better names are more descriptive. While `i` and `j` are sometimes OK for indexes, I would greatly prefer names with more letters for almost anything even slightly more complicated. In this case, `low` and `high` might be better names for the arguments.

Comment: Just a correction, for my code `QuickSort(L, l, j)` and `QuickSort(L, j, h)`  are to be invoked

Comment: @ThePerson: You don't want `j` (the index of the pivot from the partition) to be included in the part of the list that will get sorted by the recursive calls. If you leave it in, you run the risk of infinite recursion, if some sublist keeps getting partitioned all to one side, including the pivot element.